# Multiple comma delimited values to separate row in Spark Java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below dataset.
`Column_1` is comma-separated and `Column_2` and `Column_3` are separated by Colon. All are string columns.
Every comma-separated value from `Column_1` should be a separate row in `Column_1` and the equivalent values from `Column_2` or `Column_3` should be populated. Either `column_2` or `column_3` will be populated and both will not be populated at the same time.

If the number of values in `Column_1` doesn't match with the number of equivalent values in `column_2` or `column_3` then we have to populate null (`Column_1`: `I,J` and `K,L`)

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
A,B,C,D  NULL     N1:N2:N3:N4
E,F      N5:N6    NULL
G        NULL     N7
H        NULL     NULL
I,J      NULL     N8
K,L      N9       NULL
```

I have to convert the delimited values into rows as below.

```
Column_1 Column_2
A        N1
B        N2
C        N3
D        N4
E        N5
F        N6
G        N7
H        NULL
I        N8
J        NULL
K        N9
L        NULL
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Java spark API without using UDF's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala solution... should be similar in Java. You can combine columns 2 and 3 using `coalesce`, split them with the appropriate delimiter, use `arrays_zip` to transpose, and `explode` the results into rows.

```
df.select(
    explode(
        arrays_zip(
            split(col("Column_1"), ","), 
            coalesce(
                split(coalesce(col("Column_2"), col("Column_3")), ":"), 
                array()
            )
        )
    ).alias("result")
).select(
    "result.*"
).toDF(
    "Column_1", "Column_2"
).show

+--------+--------+
|Column_1|Column_2|
+--------+--------+
|       A|      N1|
|       B|      N2|
|       C|      N3|
|       D|      N4|
|       E|      N5|
|       F|      N6|
|       G|      N7|
|       H|    null|
|       I|      N8|
|       J|    null|
|       K|      N9|
|       L|    null|
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using `transform` function you can iterate over element of `column_1` and create map that you explode later:

```java
df.withColumn(
    "mappings",
    split(coalesce(col("Column_2"), col("Column_3")), ":")
).selectExpr(
    "explode(transform(split(Column_1, ','), (x, i) -> map(x, mappings[i]))) as mappings"
).selectExpr(
    "explode(mappings) as (Column_1, Column_2)"
).show()

//+--------+--------+
//|Column_1|Column_2|
//+--------+--------+
//|       A|      N1|
//|       B|      N2|
//|       C|      N3|
//|       D|      N4|
//|       E|      N5|
//|       F|      N6|
//|       G|      N7|
//|       H|    null|
//|       I|      N8|
//|       J|    null|
//|       K|      N9|
//|       L|    null|
//+--------+--------+
```